# Active directory in google cloud instance

Tags: active-directory, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, site-to-site-vpn

I want to set up an active directory in a google cloud instance and connect **local** computers with it.

I have configured the active directory in an instance, but cannot connect with the domain from local computers.

By ipconfig command in the instance, I am getting ens4, which is showing internal IP of that instance. I think I cannot connect local computers with internal IP. So I entered public IP of that instance in the IPV4 DNS server section in the local as well as tried to add this public IP in the DNS of the instance, but every I am getting a validation error.

Can anybody guide me to set up a stable active directory in google cloud instance and connect local computers with it?

Comment: You need to set-up VPN between Google Cloud and On-Prem netwerok

Comment: Have you been able to set it up?

Comment: No, though I can connect two instances with VPN but unable to connect with local. Is it because of our on-premise router as it is DHCP connection?

Comment: Thanks. I have set up an AD and able connect with it using VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To join your on premise machines to the AD I believe that the best way to proceed is to create a VPN as suggested by Gen. Try to go through the [official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-vpns) regarding Google Cloud VPNs that will show you the most common implementation to create a tunnel.

If correctly configured you will be able to use internal IPs and connect them as if they were instances of Google Compute Engine on the same VPC.

I would suggest also to take a look to this Document:

- [Deploying a Fault-Tolerant Microsoft Active Directory Environment](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploy-fault-tolerant-active-directory-environment), it shows you how to deploy and join compute engine windows instances to the AD hosted in Google Cloud.

**UPDATE**
Remember to check [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls), you have to make sure that the traffic related to AD is allowed by the rules (if not explicitly allowed but the rules the traffic is dropped, whitelist pattern)